# I installed Laravel 7 and complete all this process but now the auth is not recognized by laravel more deatail in image

Tags: authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwhWr.png)hacZ4.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use full namespace or import the dependency, like

```
// replace the namespace with the namespace of the package you are using. But more likley you should add the packages service provider into the list of service providers in config/app.php

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::routes()
```